# Getting antisamy-esapi.xml not found exception while trying to use OWASP ESAPI library

Tags: java, owasp, esapi, antisamy

I am trying to use getValidSafeHtml () function of esapi library but getting the following exception

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException : Couldn't find antisamy-esapi.xml
```

I have copied `antisamy-esapi.xml` in the same directory where I kept `ESAPI.properties` and `validation.properties` and both loads properly but getting `antisamy-esapi.xml` not found exception.
Please help as I am stuck with this error from the last two days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of esapi are you using?

Comment: Update to esapi 2.1.0.  Not only does it fix some crypto vulnerabilities identified by MITRE, it sheds a ton of dependencies... I don't believe it has an antisamy dependency.

Comment: using 2.1.0.1 and still can't fix this issue. (still wants antisamy)

Answer (score 1):

make a folder named 'esapi' at the path of ESAPI.properties, move antisamy-esapi.xml into the folder 'esapi', clean the project and try again~

```
|
|--ESAPI.properties
|--esapi
   |--antisamy-esapi.xml
```

Comment: doesn't work and from looking at the source (DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java) it appears to want ".esapi" not "esapi"  (not sure how to make a folder starting with a dot in windows using tomcat, but if there is a trick, I am game)